# SSIS error caused by 'EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_is_starting @retval OUTPUT'

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-job, sql-agent

I have a ssis package (and configuration file) developed for sql2012 to start sql agent job. The following commands are used throughout the package:

```
msdb.dbo.sp_start_job

msdb.dbo.sp_help_job

msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory
```

**And, i get the error message below when execute it as user with rights to start sql agent job at the step level.**

> Code: 0xC0202009    Source: gather data OLE DB Source [20]
>   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The metadata could not be determined because statement
>   'EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_is_starting @retval OUTPUT' in
>   procedure 'sp_is_sqlagent_starting' invokes an extended stored
>   procedure.".

I had tried the following:

- had the DBA granted the grant execute permission on
  `master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_is_starting` but that did not fix it. 
  Execute the package as sysadmin. This works fine
- Turned off and one some option on the package configuration file for
  OLEDB connection. This did not seem to affect the issue in question.
- Everywhere i looked, the problem seems to be related to `openrowset`
  which i don't use in my package.

Is there a solution to this (other than execute as sysadmin)?

Thanks

Comment: Try this link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2012/07/12/workaround-sql-server-2012-openrowset-on-sp_help_job-throws-the-metadata-could-not-be-determined/

Comment: @TheGameiswar, as mentioned in my question - i do not use openrowset in my package.

Comment: the point is metadata can't be determined,so try to wrap stored procedure output

Comment: @TheGameiswar, the job starting command does not return output. Why there is a need to wrap stored procedure output?